# Tagged PDF for 508 compliance

Tags: pdf, accessibility, section508, tagged-pdf

How can I edit a tagged PDF with Tags specifically created for [508 compliance](https://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/pdf-accessibility-wcag-508-compliance-standards.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrobat 8 & 9 have limited tag editing and creation capabilities. http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/acrobat_508.html

There is an Acrobat plugin, CommonLook http://www.commonlook.com/ , that claims to be able to edit 508 tagging.